# Java Stax ClassCastException

Tags: java, xml, stax, xalan

All,

I have the following code which converts a `Source` to a `String`. This was working until I added `jackson-dataformat-xml` to my maven POM. Unfortunately, I do need this dependency.

```
try {
   final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
   final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   final StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

   transformer.transform(source, result);

   return writer.toString();

} catch (final Exception e) {
   throw new IOException(e);
}
```

Having added `jackson-dataformat-xml`, I am receiving the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.NamespaceEventImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXEvent2SAX.handleEndElement(StAXEvent2SAX.java:342) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXEvent2SAX.bridge(StAXEvent2SAX.java:199) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.StAXEvent2SAX.parse(StAXEvent2SAX.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
  [the-above-code]
```

I've tried a few things, like manually setting the `TransformerFactory`, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `source`?

Comment: @Andreas It is a `javax.xml.transform.Source` containing xml.

Comment: I meant, what type of `Source`? `DOMSource`, `JAXBSource`, `SAXSource`, `StAXSource`, or `StreamSource`? Basically, how did you create the `source` object?

Comment: I can reproduce the error using `StAXSource(XMLEventReader)`. Look like it's a compatibility problem between `xalan` and `stax`. I try to replace `xalan` with `saxon`. But it does not support `XMLEventReader`...